# Is it possible to use systemd-networkd and have a GUI configuration tool when using GNOME?

Tags: arch-linux, gui, systemd-networkd

After reading the Archlinux guide and completed a successful installation, I would like to use networkd with GNOME if possible.

To my understanding (From the archlinux wiki) to have GUI support to configure the network in a Desktop environment like GNOME or KDE it is a must to install Network Manager. Isn't it possible to have one when using netoworkd? I prefer to use the network manager preinstalled instead of Network Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNOME network administration interfaces directly build upon NetworkManager's capabilities. So, no, that's not possible. I'd also point out that if you regularly do things like log into new WiFis etc, then networkd might simply not be the networking manager of choice – that's *exactly* what the human-use-case focused NetworkManager excels.